Response event hanlder did not trigger
I am testing titanium-web-proxy .net package 3.2.0 and have found something weird. I am able to capture requests and all is looking good, but the event handler bound to the BeforeResponse event is not triggered when a web page is loaded. This event is raised sometimes on background post events. This is the code I am using:
 proxyServer.BeforeResponse += OnResponse;

    private static async Task OnResponse(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
    {
        // read response headers
        var responseHeaders = e.HttpClient.Response.Headers;
        Console.WriteLine($"**Response ** {responseHeaders}");
        //if (!e.ProxySession.Request.Host.Equals("medeczane.sgk.gov.tr")) return;
        if (e.HttpClient.Request.Method == "GET" || e.HttpClient.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            if (e.HttpClient.Response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                if (e.HttpClient.Response.ContentType != null && e.HttpClient.Response.ContentType.Trim().ToLower().Contains("text/html"))
                {
                    byte[] bodyBytes = await e.GetResponseBody();
                    e.SetResponseBody(bodyBytes);

                    string body = await e.GetResponseBodyAsString();
                    e.SetResponseBodyString(body);
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.UserData != null)
        {
            // access request from UserData property where we stored it in RequestHandler
            var request = (Request)e.UserData;
        }
    }

Is this a bug? or maybe I missed out something, regarding setup? or furthermore is something about the SSL certicate?  I appreciate any clues on this matter.
